# Add a year to a date in string format using php

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date in a string format such as `string(10) "30/08/2014"` and i need to add a year to it. In my case i'll have `30/08/2015` I was trying to use something like this but i am failing...

```
        $start = new DateTime($details['start_date']);
        $start->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
        $end_date = $start;
```

any suggestion please? thank you!

The error i get now is `"DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (30/08/2014) at position 0 (3): Unexpected character"`
Do I have to format the string such as `Y-m-d` or there is a fastest and more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add one year to that date. Example:

```
// you have to define the format of the date that you're feeding
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '30/08/2014'); // create format first ($details['start_date'])
// then use the method ->add() and feed it with a DateInterval Object with the proper interval
$start->add(new DateInterval('P1Y')); // add the year
$end = $start->format('d/m/Y'); // assign it to a variable
echo $end; // 30/08/2015
```

Comment: +1 great answer. I'm unfamiliar with the code. Please elaborate what code is that ghost thanks :)

Comment: Is that using classes? OOP? or something?

Comment: @JohnRobertson yes its an actual built in class of PHP. [here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 3):

This might do the trick for you.

```
$end_date = strtotime(date($details['start_date'])." + 1 year");
```

`strtotime` function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

convert date in Y-m-d format

```
$var = '20/04/2012';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 year", strtotime($date)));
```

As, PHP doesn't work well with dd/mm/yyyy format.

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = '25/05/2010';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
echo  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 year", strtotime($date)));
```

Result:

```
2010-05-25
```

The strtotime documentation reads:

```
Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator
between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the 
American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), 
then the European d-m-y format is assumed.
```